# File seek with two-byte characters

Tags: go, unicode, seek

I'm writing small log parser, which should find some tags in files.
Files are large (512mb) and have the following structure:

```
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:125] VersionInfo\886
...some data...
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:109][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->IncomingTime\16
...some data...
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:109][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->IncomingData\397
...some data...
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:749][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->OutgoingData\26651
...somedata...
```

Each block `IncomingTime, IncomingData, OutgoingData, etc.` has block size (characters count, not bytes) at the end `886, 16, 397, 26651`. Some blocks are very large and can't be read without large buffer (if i use bufio). I want to skip unnecessary blocks using `file.Seek`.

The problem is that `file.Seek` needs bytes length and i've only characters count (block may have unicode data with two-byte charcters). Is there any chance to skip blocks using characters count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that file.Seek needs bytes length and i've only characters count (block may have unicode data with two-byte charcters). Is there any chance to skip blocks using characters count?

That's actually impossible.  As you've described the file format, both of the following are possible:

```
...VersionInfo\1
[ 20 ]
...VersionInfo\1
[ C2 A0 ]
```

If you've just read the newline and you know you need to read one character, you know it's somewhere between 1 and 2 bytes (UTF-8 characters can go up to 4 bytes even) but not which, and blindly launching forward some number of bytes without inspecting the intermediate data won't work.  The pathological case is a larger block, where the first half has many multi-byte characters and the last half has text that happens to look like one of your entry headers.

With this file format you're forced to read it a character at a time.